# PWM Return Problem

Tags: pwm, grounding, ground-loop

A controller send pwm signal with 2 wires
 1- PWM 2- PWM Return
But servo motor has 1 input pin. So is it correct to use servo supply return (28v Gnd)or servo chassis input for controller pwm return connection?
What is correct tendecy for PWM grounding. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most such devices use the power supply (-) lead as the return line for the signal.

Comment: Servo also has chassis input  may it also shorted to power return? And power return is always the solution?  Thanks.